# I have DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'productID'

Tags: sql

```
Select productid,
       (
           Select name
           From   menu
           Where  id = productid
       ) As Foodname,
       price,
       quantity,
       price * quantity As total
From   salesdetail
Where  salesid = (
                     Select id
                     From   booking
                     Where  secret = 'ypnok3bd'
                            And id = 'SSD00000000000000001'
                 );
```

DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'productID'. I had checked that the fields are correct but why it still cannot?

```
 <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Food ID</td>
            <td>Food Name</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Total</td>

        </tr>

        <asp:ListView ID="listView1" runat="server">

            <ItemTemplate>

                <tr>
                    <td><%# Eval("productID") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("Foodname") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("quantity") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("price") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("total") %></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>

    </table>
```

Comment: It's named `productid`, *not* `productID`.

Comment: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'productid'.

I get the same error....

Comment: you have to show your code on how you're filling that Listview

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class check : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection();
        MySqlCommand cmmd = new MySqlCommand();
        connection.ConnectionString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=pf;UID=root;PASSWORD=password;";
        connection.Open();
        string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM booking where secret = '"+ txtcode.Text + "' and id = '"+ txtorid.Text +"'";
        MySqlDataAdapter adapt = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdText, connection);
        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        adapt.Fill(t);
        listView.DataSource = t;
        listView.DataBind();
        listView.Visible = true;
        connection.Close();
    //MySqlConnection Conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=pf;Uid=root;Pwd=password;");
    //MySqlCommand Command = new MySqlCommand();
    //Conn.Open();
    //Command.Connection = Conn;
    //Command.CommandText = "SELECT productid, (select name from menu where id = productid)as Foodname, price, quantity, price * quantity as total from salesdetail where salesid = (select id from booking where secret = 'ypnok3bd' and id = 'SSD00000000000000001') ";

    ////string productid = Command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    ////string Foodname = Command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    ////string price = Command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    ////string total = Command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    //DataTable d = new DataTable();
    //adapt.Fill(d);
    //listView1.DataSource = d;
    //listView1.DataBind();
    //listView1.Visible = true;
    //Conn.Close();

}

protected void btncheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of post as answer.